# VHDL analysis issue with GHDL

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

I have written some vhdl code which contains the implementation of a half adder. It is a few lines of code and has no bugs.

When I compile it with ghdl it produces the `.o` file for the corresponding vhdl file. But when I execute `ghdl -e filename`, the following error occurs:

```
*error: cannot find entity or configuration demo*  
*/usr/lib/ghdl/bin/ghdl: compilation error*
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The ghdl -e command takes the entity name, instead of a file name.

I happened to have a ghdl example lying around. It has a Makefile, so simply typing **make** should get it compiled, after which you can run **tb_adder**:
http://kapsi.fi/~jpa/stuff/other/ghdl-example.tar.gz